# Windows 7 machine not pulling DHCP-issued address

Tags: windows-7, dhcp, windows-firewall

Not sure where to go on this one.  `netsh winsock reset` and `netsh int ip reset` did not help.  If I set a static IP on the machine, it communicates fine.  But it won't pull a DHCP address.

Here's where it gets weird.  If I stop the Windows Firewall service, it pulls a DHCP without issue.  Then I can turn the service back on and everything continues to work.  But if the service is on while trying to pull an IP, it fails.  This only happens on our Windows 7 machines.  It does not happen on our Vista machines.

Comment: Have you or anyone else made any modifications to the Windows Firewall rules? (Is there a button you can click to "reset" them to defaults?)

Comment: There are a few general changes forced by Group Policy.  I can't change them, but I can take it off the domain and see what happens, I suppose.  I'll let you know after that.

Comment: Try resetting rules as said by Darth, Here is [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Restore-Windows-Firewall-settings) to Restore Windows Firewall Settings. Firewall prevents communication with DHCP server in situation like [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2344959).

Comment: That article is the issue, Mayur.  Just confirmed.  Post as an answer, and I'll choose it.  Thanks!